# Error while converting video to frames with ffmpeg

Tags: ffmpeg, video-processing

When I'm executing the conversion command in cmd, it fails to get the output.
[image: cmd output of the command]

Comment: 1) ffmpeg won't create folders, they must already exist; 2) make sure your relative path is correct. Looks like you're adding the current directory to the path as well - that should be removed.

Comment: I had already created the folder. Removing the 'data' from the command worked. Thanks!